# Problema al compilar Sass en Atom (Win 10)

Tags: css, sass, scss, atom-editor

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Sass, en **Windows 10**. Uso el editor Atom y el preprocesador **Prepros**. Tengo instalado Nodejs.

El problema es que cuando quise compilar por primera vez el archivo sass, me salió esto en Atom:

> [ "node-sass" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. ]

Alguien podría darme una mano con esto?

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que ejecutar esto en la consola:

```
npm install -g node-sass.
```